# Find Site Collection where a subsite belongs to using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

From this subsite:

http://mysite.mydomain.com/services/employee/personnel

How do i determine which site collection it belongs to? (which in this case would be 'http://mysite.mydomain.com/services/employee')

Answer (score 0):

Below powershell script will help you find the site collection:

```
$web=Get-SPWeb http://mysite.mydomain.com/services/employee/personnel
$web.site
```